# Serve static resources using Clojure's Ring

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I am learning how to create web apps using Clojure's Ring. I'm trying to serve a static **.html** file which contains a reference to a .css file through a `<link>` tag in its head part. The .css file is in the same directory as the index.html file I'm trying to serve, however, the .css file is not being loaded (I get an error with a 500 status code with a reason phrase of:

> Reponse map is nil

This is my code below:

```
(defroutes approutes
  (GET "/" reqmap
    (resource-response "index.html")))


(def server (run-jetty #'approutes {:join? false, :port 3000}))
```

What am I missing here? and how can I serve an html file that has references to other files (.css, .js, .jpeg, etc)? I've had some luck (although I can't completly explain why) using Ring's `wrap-resource` middleware in the `ring.middleware.resource` namespace although that function is to be used only when a request map matches a static resource (and as you can see, the route "/" doesn't match a resource per-se).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add one bit of middleware that will take care of serving static files from a folder you can select, something like the following:

```clj
;; Add to your (ns :requires at the top of the file)
(:require [ring.middleware.resource :refer wrap-resource])

;; more of your existing code here...

(def app
  (wrap-resource approutes "public")) ;; serve static files from "resources/public" in your project

(def server (run-jetty #'app {:join? false, :port 3000}))
```

This should be enough to get you going, so if you start your server, you should be able to open files in addresses such as http://localhost:3000/style.css which should be found in `public/resources/style.css` in your project. Any other static files should work. There's a guide in the [Ring wiki in Github](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Static-Resources) that explains two similar functions (middlewares) that you can use.

Next, in your `index.html` file you should be able to reference other files such as CSS files, like the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <!-- and son on... -->
```

Here's a sample project I wrote a while ago that does show the same ideas: https://github.com/dfuenzalida/antizer-demo

---

***UPDATE***

I've done a quick run from scratch, this should help you find what the problem is.

Created a new project with:

```
lein new app hello-ring
```

Actually, the name is a bit misleading because we'll be using both Ring and Compojure.

We'll update the file `project.clj` with the following:

```clj
(defproject hello-ring "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.6.3"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.6.3"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot hello-ring.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Now let's edit the file `src/hello_ring/core.clj`, its contents should be like the following:

```clj
(ns hello-ring.core
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]
            [ring.middleware.resource :refer [wrap-resource]]
            [ring.util.response :refer [resource-response]]
            [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET]])
  (:gen-class))

(defroutes approutes
  (GET "/" []
       (resource-response "public/index.html")))

(def app
  (-> approutes
      (wrap-resource "public"))) ;; files from resources/public are served

(defn server []
  (run-jetty app {:join? false, :port 3000}))

(defn -main [& args]
  (server))
```

Finally let's create a couple of static resources. Create the folder structure `resources/public/css` and in the file `resources/public/css/style.css` enter the following:

```css
body {
    font-face: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

... and a basic HTML file in `resources/public/index.html` with the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>It works!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>it works!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

... that's it. The HTML file will attempt to load the CSS file. Save everything and check if it matches the following folder structure:

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── doc
│   └── intro.md
├── LICENSE
├── project.clj
├── README.md
├── resources
│   └── public
│       ├── css
│       │   └── style.css
│       └── index.html
├── src
│   └── hello_ring
│       └── core.clj
└── test
    └── hello_ring
        └── core_test.clj
```

Now you should be able to start the service from the command line with:

```
lein run
```

The output will look like the following:

```
$ lein run
2019-08-05 23:46:14.919:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1221ms
2019-08-05 23:46:16.281:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.21.v20170120
2019-08-05 23:46:16.303:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2c846d55{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:3000}
2019-08-05 23:46:16.303:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @2606ms
```

Connect to the server in http://0.0.0.0:3000/ ... You should see your page in the browser with the **It works!** message and a basic CSS reset. In the console you're most likely to see some exceptions because the browser attempts to load the file `/favicon.ico` from your server, which does not exist (you can create it as an empty file for now).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried this: `(defroutes approutes
  (GET "/" reqmap {:status 200 :body (slurp "resources/public/index.html")}))


  (def app (wrap-resource approutes "public"))
    


(def server (run-jetty #'app {:join? false, :port 3000}))` and was able to see the `index.html` load on my localhost... but still, it's not pulling the .css file declared in its `<head>`  ... is this part of the expected behavior?

Comment: it should work for static resources of all types. I'm guessing the issue is in the configuration somewhere. Please check my update to the answer and check if the paths in your project are correct (maybe your CSS file is in another folder or there's a typo somewhere)

Comment: It works with your code from the edit. Thank you!. I'll figure out what it is on my code that's not pulling the css correctly (it's pulling the html file, but not the css). Again, thanks a lot man!.