# Adding static files to compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I need to add leaningen project

> my-compojure/src/dist/output.css

from tailwind to my compojure project. Where should I put it?

After starting the server, I am naively calling

```
localhost:3000/dist/output.css
```

But that does not work.

Does anybody know, how I can add these static files in compojure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serve static resources using Clojure's Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367826/serve-static-resources-using-clojures-ring)

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the static files from your server. When using Leiningen you can place the file in the resources/public folder in the root. Ensure the `project.clj` points to the resource folder with `:resource-paths ["resources"]`. Then serve the resources folder using Compojure:

```clj
(:require [ring.middleware.resource :refer [wrap-resource]])

(def app
  (wrap-resource approutes "public")) ; serve static files from "resources/public"

(def server (run-jetty #'app {:join? false, :port 3000}))
```

See [Serve static resources using Clojure's Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368018/2609980) for a more elaborate example.